# Does the ferry count towards journey distance?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

If I do a journey that's < 155 miles land distance, but the ferry distance is > 155 miles, will I get a long driving XP bonus for doing more than 155 miles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did an experiment, but I couldn't find such a short route. Here's what I chose:[image]

It's 511km on land and 370km by ferry, which of course come together as 881km after I attached the trailer:[image]

And here's the job completed screen with the reward details: [image]

My base reward was €15,813, long distance bonus €1,421, which is 8.9%, in terms of XP: base 516, long distance 129 (25%).

My ranking screen: [image]

This cargo qualifies for rank 2, because the distance is more than 350km, but less than 850km. I should get 10% extra money and 25% extra XP, which I almost got (8.9% and 25%). If the calculation included the ferry distance, I would've qualified for rank 3, meaning 15% extra money, which I clearly didn't get.

## Conclusion

Ferry distance does not count toward the journey distance when calculating your reward. Only on your gps.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it does and it sometimes is discouraging when you see a high amount of hours that you have to drive.